# Use Crypto++ RSA::PublicKey to decrypt cipher text

Tags: c++, rsa, private-key, crypto++

I have the n, d, e for RSA algorithm. However, I want to use private_key to encrypt some string, generate *USER_CERTIFICATION*, and use public_key for users to decrypt it and get the string. I know if I do so, the string can be easily decrypted by anyone, but security is **not** my concern at all, I just need that **no one except me** can generate the *USER_CERTIFICATION*

I'm using CryptoPP, the code for encoding works fine:

```
Integer _n(...), _e(...), _d(...);
AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
RSA::PrivateKey k;
k.Initialize(_n, _e, _d);
RSAES_PKCS1v15_Encryptor enc(k);
std::string cipher;
StringSource ss1( plain, true,
    new PK_EncryptorFilter( rng, enc,
        new StringSink( cipher )) // PK_EncryptorFilter
    ); // StringSource
```

but the decryption code throws an exception: "class CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction: Missing required parameter 'Prime1'"

```
Integer _n(...), _e(...);

AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
RSA::PublicKey k;
k.Initialize(_n, _e);
RSAES_PKCS1v15_Decryptor dec(k);
std::string plain;
StringSource ss1( cipher, true,
    new PK_DecryptorFilter( rng, dec,
        new StringSink( plain ))
    ); // StringSource
```

Is it possible to do this with CryptoPP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use private_key to encrypt some string

Usually, when you ask for *encrypt with the private key*, what you want is a *Probablistic Signature with Recovery (PSSR)* scheme. By the way, *encrypt with the private key* is ***not*** a valid cryptographic transformation :)

The [`cryptlib.h` header](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/cryptlib_8h.html) is described as *Abstract base classes that provide a uniform interface to this library*. All Crypto++ Signers and Verifiers adhere to the [`PK_SignatureScheme`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_p_k___signature_scheme.html) interface. Signers further implement [`PK_Signer`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_p_k___signer.html), while Verifiers further implement [`PK_Verifier`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_p_k___verifier.html).

The Crypto++ RSA objects would look like so:

```
RSASS<PSSR, SHA256>::Signer signer;
RSASS<PSSR, SHA256>::Verifier verifier;
```

The Crypto++ Rabin objects would look like so:

```
RabinSS<PSSR, SHA256>::Signer signer;
RabinSS<PSSR, SHA256>::Verifier verifier;
```

The Crypto++ Rabin-Williams objects would look like so:

```
RWSS<PSSR, SHA256>::Signer signer;
RWSS<PSSR, SHA256>::Verifier verifier;
```

the objects are consistent, and you can swap them in and out.

By the way, you should look into Rabin-Williams to see if it fits your needs. Also see Bernstein's [RSA signatures and Rabin–Williams signatures: the state of the art](http://cr.yp.to/sigs/rwsota-20080131.pdf).

---

> I'm using CryptoPP, the code for encoding works fine ...

Scrap it. The exponent you are using is well known, so there's no real security in what you are doing. There are ways to improve the security, but it sounds like you want a PSSR instead.

Here are the two example of using RSA's PSSR from the wiki:

- [RSA Probabilistic Signature Scheme with Recovery](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes#RSA_Probabilistic_Signature_Scheme_with_Recovery)
- [RSA Probabilistic Signature Scheme with Recovery (Filter)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes#RSA_Probabilistic_Signature_Scheme_with_Recovery_.28Filter.29)

And here's the signer code for [RSA Probabilistic Signature Scheme with Recovery](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes#RSA_Probabilistic_Signature_Scheme_with_Recovery) with some of your stuff dialed in. Note that you need a real [`RandomNumberGenerator`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator) because the signature is randomized.

```
Integer n(...), e(...), d(...);
RSA::PrivateKey key(n,e,d);
RSASS<PSSR, SHA256>::Signer signer(key);

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Sign and Encode
SecByteBlock signature(signer.MaxSignatureLength(messageLen));

AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
size_t signatureLen = signer.SignMessageWithRecovery(rng, message, messageLen, NULL, 0, signature);

// Resize now we know the true size of the signature
signature.resize(signatureLen);
```

---

And here's the verifier code for [RSA Probabilistic Signature Scheme with Recovery](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes#RSA_Probabilistic_Signature_Scheme_with_Recovery) with some of your stuff dialed in. Note that you don't need [`RandomNumberGenerator`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator), so you can use `NullRNG()` if its needed somewhere.

```
Integer n(...), e(...);
RSA::PublicKey key(n,e);
RSASS<PSSR, SHA256>::Verifier verifier(key);

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Verify and Recover
SecByteBlock recovered(
    verifier.MaxRecoverableLengthFromSignatureLength(signatureLen)
);

DecodingResult result = verifier.RecoverMessage(recovered, NULL, 0, signature, signatureLen);

if (!result.isValidCoding) {
    throw Exception(Exception::OTHER_ERROR, "Invalid Signature");
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Use recovered message
//  MaxSignatureLength is likely larger than messageLength
recovered.resize(result.messageLength);
```

---

> ... but the decryption code throws an exception: "class CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction: Missing required parameter 'Prime1'"

Yep, *encrypt with the private key* is ***not*** a valid cryptographic transformation. I'm pretty sure *decrypt with the public key* is ***not*** valid, either :)

---

I'm not going to provide the code for encryption and decryption since I don't believe you need it. But you can find it at [RSA Encryption Schemes](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Rsa_encryption_schemes) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: SignatureWithRecovery works, but it cannot handle message larger than 128 bytes. Spliting long message into many 128-byte-chunks seems not a good idea. Now I use `a_exp_b_mod_c(message, d, n)` to do the encoding myself .

Comment: @aj3423 - Just so there are no surprises... your message is still too big. `a_exp_b_mod_c` silently truncates it. If you perform the reverse transformation, then you will get a truncated message back. Check out [Raw RSA](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA), and examine the message you recover (the relevant section is [Private Key Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA#Private_Key_Encryption)). To avoid the truncation: is it possible to increase the size of the modulus or use a smaller message?

Comment: @aj3423 - Also be sure you *really* want to forgo randomization on the signature. The cited Bernstein paper talks about why you want to randomize a signature in Section 5. The attacks against non-randomized signatures have been around since 1979.

Comment: Yes I have to split messages into 244-byte pieces for pkcs1v15 padding, I think 244 is still better than 128 bytes.  I'll try the `ApplyFunction` + `CalculateInverse` later, thanks.

Comment: @aj3423 - Sounds good. You might also want to search on Google Scholar: ["pss-r" large message](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q="pss-r"+"large+message") to see what some of the alternatives are that fit you needs.

Comment: @aj3423 - How did you make out with your recovery experiments?

Comment: Maybe I cannot use `ApplyFunction` anyway, because It requires all the three arguments n,e,**d** to initialize the RSA::PrivateKey. I cannot leak the both **e** and **d** to my clients. I've no idea why RSA::PrivateKey requires three of them to initialize, I think theoretically it should be ok with just two of them.

Comment: @jww you are not right, Encryption with the private key is completely legit operation it's base of mathematics underlying RSA. If it wasn't you would not be able to use RSA for signing.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to sign a message with your private key? This link has an example, maybe it helps (code and link below). Note also that not all signing is encryption. For example, ECDSA used by Bitcoin uses a signing operation that takes a random number as one input, no encryption is done as part of signing.

https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/User_Guide:_rsa.h

```
void Sign()
{
string strContents = "A message to be signed";
//FileSource("tobesigned.dat", true, new StringSink(strContents));

AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

//Read private key
CryptoPP::ByteQueue bytes;
FileSource file("privkey.txt", true, new Base64Decoder);
file.TransferTo(bytes);
bytes.MessageEnd();
RSA::PrivateKey privateKey;
privateKey.Load(bytes);

//Sign message
RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Signer privkey(privateKey);
SecByteBlock sbbSignature(privkey.SignatureLength());
privkey.SignMessage(
   rng,
   (byte const*) strContents.data(),
   strContents.size(),
   sbbSignature);

   //Save result
   FileSink sink("signed.dat");
   sink.Put((byte const*) strContents.data(), strContents.size());
   FileSink sinksig("sig.dat");
   sinksig.Put(sbbSignature, sbbSignature.size());
}
```

Comment: @jwwYes, but it seems to me what he wants to do is the classic compute-hash-of-msg->encrypt--hash-with-private-key. Then, the recipient can verify the autenticity of msg by using sender:s public key if that key is CA-verified and trusted.